# Could not resolve CoreCLR path in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: .net, ubuntu-20.04

When I want to run the `.dll` file in the Ubuntu system, this error :

> Could not resolve CoreCLR path. For more details, enable tracing by setting COREHOST_TRACE environment variable to 1

Can any of you help me?

[image]

Comment: So what's the output of `dotnet --info`?

Comment: What's the output of `ls`? Did you try setting `COREHOST_TRACE` to 1, as suggested in the error?

Comment: you uploaded an Windows/Other Platform build on Linux

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with .Net 6.0 in an Ubuntu AWS instance. It turns out that you have to include `--self-contained` option when publishing, like this:

```
dotnet publish backend/bundle_name.sln -c release -r linux-x64 -o /artifacts/bin --self-contained
```

You also have to set `RuntimeIdentifier` in you csprojects. See this another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70252627/error-netsdk1031-it-is-not-supported-to-build-or-publish-a-self-contained-appli).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, the probles was a corrupted asp.net application. I published it as self contained app and after that as framework-dependent without clearing the publish directory.

After deleteing all files from publish directory and republishing, it worked.